# How to create Reusable EditForm blazor component with Dynamic/TValue model?

Tags: blazor, syncfusion

I am trying to create a reusable EditForm template with generic datatype and call inside Grid Edit Settings for data entry and modifications.

Below is my Grid Edit Setting

```
<SfGrid @ref="SimpleGrid" ID="@GridID" DataSource="@DataSourceList" Toolbar="@ToolbarItems" TValue="TValue">         
   <GridEditSettings AllowAdding="@IsEditable" AllowDeleting="@IsEditable" AllowEditing="@IsEditable"   Mode="@EditMode.Dialog" Dialog="@DialogParams">
       <Validator>
               <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
       </Validator>
       <Template>
             <EditFormTest></EditFormTest>
       </Template>
   </GridEditSettings> 
</SfGrid> 
@code 
{     
   [Parameter] public List<TValue>? DataSourceList { get; set; } 
}
```

Below is my EditFormTest code:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using LightWeigh_POS.Shared.Components
@using LightWeigh_Pos.Data.Models
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Inputs

<h3>Dynamic form</h3>

    
    @CreateComponent()
    
    
        Save
    


@code {

    ImageModel employeeDetails;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        employeeDetails = new ImageModel();
    }
    
    public RenderFragment CreateComponent() => builder =>
    {
        var proList = typeof(ImageModel).GetProperties();
        foreach (var prp in proList)
        {
            Type T = prp.GetType();
            if (prp.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataTypeAttribute), false).Length != 0)
            {
                var attrList = (DataTypeAttribute)prp.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataTypeAttribute), false).First();
                var displayLabel = (DisplayAttribute)prp.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false).First();
                // Get the initial property value
                var propInfoValue = typeof(ImageModel).GetProperty(prp.Name);
                // Create an expression to set the ValueExpression-attribute.
                var constant = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(employeeDetails, typeof(ImageModel));
                var exp = System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Property(constant, prp.Name);
                switch (attrList.DataType)
                {
                    case DataType.Text:
                    case DataType.EmailAddress:
                    case DataType.PhoneNumber:
                    case DataType.MultilineText:
                        {
                            builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(SfTextBox));
                            // Create the handler for ValueChanged. I use reflection to the value.
                            builder.AddAttribute(3, "ValueChanged", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.String>>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<System.String>(this, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.CreateInferred(this, __value => propInfoValue.SetValue(employeeDetails, __value), (string)propInfoValue.GetValue(employeeDetails)))));
                            builder.AddAttribute(4, "ValueExpression", System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(exp));
                            if (attrList.DataType == DataType.MultilineText)
                                builder.AddAttribute(5, "Multiline", true);
                            break;
                        }
                    case DataType.Date:
                        builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(Syncfusion.Blazor.Calendars.SfDatePicker<DateTime?>));
                        builder.AddAttribute(3, "ValueChanged", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<DateTime?>>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<DateTime?>(this, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.CreateInferred(this, __value => propInfoValue.SetValue(employeeDetails, __value), (DateTime?)propInfoValue.GetValue(employeeDetails)))));
                        builder.AddAttribute(4, "ValueExpression", System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<DateTime?>>(exp));
                        break;
                    case DataType.Duration:
                        builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(SfNumericTextBox<decimal?>));
                        builder.AddAttribute(3, "ValueChanged", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<decimal?>>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<decimal?>(this, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.CreateInferred(this, __value => propInfoValue.SetValue(employeeDetails, __value), (decimal?)propInfoValue.GetValue(employeeDetails)))));
                        builder.AddAttribute(4, "ValueExpression", System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<decimal?>>(exp));
                        break;
                    case DataType.Custom:
                        
                        builder.AddAttribute(3, "ValueChanged", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.String>>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<System.String>(this, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.CreateInferred(this, __value => propInfoValue.SetValue(employeeDetails, __value), (string)propInfoValue.GetValue(employeeDetails)))));
                        builder.AddAttribute(4, "ValueExpression", System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(exp));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                var defaultValue = propInfoValue.GetValue(employeeDetails);
                builder.AddAttribute(1, "Value", defaultValue);
                builder.AddAttribute(6, "PlaceHolder", displayLabel.Name);
                builder.AddAttribute(6, "FloatLabelType", FloatLabelType.Auto);
    
                builder.CloseComponent();
            }
        }
    };
    
    public void Submit()
    {
    
    }

}
```

The above SfGrid is Syncfusion component that accepts datasource as parameter which allows me to reuse the Grid for all other pages. I want to have specific design for the EditForms and reuse inside datagrid edit template for any model that has been passed as parameter but I am not able to achieve this when I change Model in `<EditForm Model="@employeeDetails" OnValidSubmit="@Submit">` to dynamic or TValue.

Is it even possible what I am trying to achieve if yes then how ?

Reusable Dynamic Edit Form without specifying specific DataModel.

Comment: Is it even possible?  Everything is possible.  Many have tried.  There are a few questions on here about it.  I've even written one for SharePoint Forms.  Would I try again. NO, never.  You start off with the text box.  Great, not too difficult.... then you come to selects and radio buttons.  Everything starts to get horrendously complicated.  You need configuration about each field,.... I have a form framework, into which I just all the edit fields as formatted  columns .

Comment: @MrC Thanks for the comment. My second concern is how to make edit form in a way that it allows add for nested object. For example product has product categories, now when adding product we have categories drop down. But I want to give an option for add new if user wants to. How can I automate this to allow adding any submodel items ?

Comment: Can you add that as another question.

Answer (score 0):

By default Syncfusion DataGrid uses Blazor EditForm for inbuilt editing. If we use BlazorEdit form inside the DialogTemplate  feature then it will results in rendering EditForm inside the EditForm.  So it is not suggested to use standalone EditForm inside Dialog Template feature of DataGrid.

Comment: What if I want to use custom completely different design for EditForm ?